# Parse Error using $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] in php

Tags: php, php-parse-error

I am working around Define path of file using

```
<?php 
$filePath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Testfolder/testfile.php"; 
if(file_exists($filePath)) 
{ 
echo 'file exist'; 
} 
else 
{ 
echo 'File no exist'; 
} 
?>
```

but when i echo file path it gives me following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_FUNCTION

please help me this

Comment: show more code, preceding lines are often where the error lies.

Comment: I just want to check passed file is exist or not using file_exists() in php

Comment: Just give more details then we can actually help you; with the current details no way - we can make guesses (or even good estimates) but with a few lines above the code we'll be able tell much better.

Comment: <?php

    $filePath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Testfolder/testfile.php";

    if(file_exists($filePath))
    {
       echo 'file exist';
    }
    else
    {
      echo 'File no exist';
    }

?>

Comment: This is code that i have getting error

Comment: Replace with `if(file_exists($filePath)) { echo 'file exist'; } else { }`

Comment: Still same error occurs after replacing ur code

Comment: @SteveMartin - Please edit the original question when you want to provide further details. Code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: Posted code in original question

Comment: well that code is 100% functional - and to prove it: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/y5u-a0d

Comment: so the problem has to be in what are you using to call that php?

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted works perfect.
Maybe you forgot the ";" after the echo?

The question as is, is indeed working, show more code to determine the problem.
You still didn't show the echo code which is causing the problem.

Comment: Well, so I answered the question didn't I?